# Kubernetes Nginx container unable to access php-fpm container

Tags: php, docker, nginx, kubernetes, docker-compose

I've created 2 Kubernetes deployments for nginx and a php-fpm laravel container. But for some reason, traffic from nginx seems unable to successfully get to the php-fpm containers generating the following error

```
172.18.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2022:16:51:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"
```

This is my deployment file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: web-server-config
  namespace: dev-api
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php index.html;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        root /var/www/html/public;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

            fastcgi_pass api-web-svc:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                gzip_static on;
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: php-config
  namespace: dev-api
data:
  laravel.ini: |
    upload_max_filesize: 80M
    post_max_size: 80M
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: api-web-secret
  namespace: dev-api
type: Opaque
data:
 ...
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-web
  namespace: dev-api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-web
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api-web
        image: XXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api-web:0.9.4-alpha
        volumeMounts:
         - name: php-config
           mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/laravel.ini
         - name: env-config
           mountPath: /var/www/html/.env
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
      volumes:
        - name: php-config
          configMap:
            name: php-config
        - name: env-config
          secret:
            secretName: api-web-secret
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred  
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: dev-api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        volumeMounts:
         - name: web-server-config
           mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
        - name: web-server-config
          configMap:
            name: web-server-config 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  web-server-svc
  namespace: dev-api
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app:  nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port:  80
    targetPort:  80
    nodePort: 32420
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  api-web-svc
  namespace: dev-api
  labels:
    app: api-web
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app:  api-web
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port:  9000
```

The `namespace` is declared separately. The two containers in each of the deployments run successfully.

```
k logs deployment/nginx-deployment  -n dev-api
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.6
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.3.1 20211027 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.4.0-109-generic
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
2022/07/18 16:18:50 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
```

```
 k logs deployment/api-web -n dev-api
[18-Jul-2022 16:18:51] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[18-Jul-2022 16:18:51] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[18-Jul-2022 16:18:51] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[18-Jul-2022 16:18:51] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[18-Jul-2022 16:18:51] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[18-Jul-2022 16:18:51] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

And the Dockerfile used to generate the image `api-web:0.9.4-alpha` in the `api-web` deployment is as shown below

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/html/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    nodejs \
    npm

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www/html/

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www/html/

# Change current user to www
USER www

## Run composer dependencies
RUN composer update
RUN composer install

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

This Dockerfile runs fine too, with no issues. A `docker-compose` file using this image also works with no issues.

Any ideas why traffic from the `nginx-deployment` container fails to reach the `api-web` php-fpm container with the error

```
172.18.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2022:16:51:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: What's the curl request? This request you showed went to / location in Nginx and Nginx send it to /var/www/html/public of the Nginx container.

Comment: I'm running all this on Minikube.`minikube svc web-server-svc -n dev-api` opened the URL `http://172.17.0.2:32420/` on the browser. This is where the nginx request logged came from.

Comment: So if index.html or index.php doesn't exist in /var/www/html/public of the Nginx container, a 404 response is normal. Maybe you need to add proxy_pass in / location.

Comment: `index.php` does exist in /var/www/html/public. This is a typical laravel deployment. I confirmed that `index.php` does exist by logging into the  api-web container and checking the /var/www/html/public dir. As I mentioned earlier, a similar deployment in a `docker-compose`  yaml works fine.

Comment: As I know you have 2 pods or containers (api-web and nginx). "index.php" exist in the api-web (laravel) container, not in the nginx container. Would you please check "index.php" is exist in the "/var/www/html/public" of the nginx container?

Comment: @HamidOstadvali Does `index.php` need to exist in the nginx container? When writing these deployments, I actually wanted to keep the index.php and other source code files in the `api-web` container. Then I configured the nginx container to route the requests to the api-web container.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know both pods or at least the containers need the same source files. If the nginx doesn't know that this php files exists, it can not forward the request to the php-fpm container.

I'm saying container, while i wouldn't recommend to split the nginx and php-fpm into separate pods. More likely i would start those containers as one unit with the same source in one pod. Except you have some sort of Cron jobs or batch jobs.

Comment: Thanks Manuel. However, the way I wrote the deployments was than the nginx container would receive incoming requests and forward them to the api-web container via a kubernetes service. You'll see I configured the nginx passthrough to do this in `fastcgi_pass api-web-svc:9000`. This would typically have been `127.0.0.1:9000` for a non dockerized solution with nginx and php-fpm running locally. My assumption was that the nginx container would not need to be aware of the php files in the php-fpm container. Just the path to get to the php-fpm container.

Comment: Did you get it running now? You can keep it splitted as well. Still the nginx needs to know the files. What we did was to build a cusomt nginx and a custom php-fpm image that we deployed.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest maintaining both containers in a single **POD** if using the `php-fpm` however if already using the **Nginx ingress** **controller** or any other proxy support `php-fpm` in the existing setup there is no need to run the Nginx as **sidecar** or another deployment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: wordpress-site
  name: wordpress-site
  namespace: development
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress-site
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: wordpress-site
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 256
          name: nginxthroughpass
          optional: false
        name: nginxconf
      - name: shared-files
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: <REPLACE WITH DOCKER PHP-FPM IMAGE URL>
          imagePullPolicy : IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-files
              mountPath: /var/www/html
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: wordpress-configmap
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          imagePullPolicy : IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
          - name: shared-files
            mountPath: /var/www/html
          - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
            name: nginxconf
            readOnly: true
```

Repo for ref : https://github.com/harsh4870/Kubernetes-wordpress-php-fpm-nginx

**Or else**

If you don't want to run **Nginx** container you can also use the Nginx ingress to forward the traffic to **php-fpm** container

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi_send_timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi_read_timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "FCGI"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-index: "index.php"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-params-configmap: "development/word-cm"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippets: |
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass wordpress-site:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
  name: wordpress-dev
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: php-fpm-service
          servicePort: 80
```

You can also use this ingress as ref : https://github.com/harsh4870/Kubernetes-wordpress-php-fpm-nginx/blob/master/ingress.yaml

Comment: The recommended approach is almost always to run a single container in a pod, as in the original question.  Why would this rearrangement help the OP?

Comment: yes David, right you are so shared both options in answer. he can use the Nginx ingress with just a simple php-fpm single container POD.

Comment: @HarshManvar While I appreciate the response, David is right. This solution deploys both containers in a single pod with an ingress to the nginx service. I would rather have 2 deployments each with a single pod so as to separate concerns properly.

Comment: No, maybe you have misunderstood, just deploy a single deployment of `PHP fpm` and use Nginx ingress it will resolve your issue. without another deployment of nginx container, if you are already using nginx ingress it will work with existing setup. updated answer with ingress details.

Comment: Note: If you want to serve static files using nginx. Putting config to the ingress-nginx will not achieve that. ingress will ALWAYS reverse proxy the php container even for the static file. For static files to be served by nginx you will need the sidecar.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Sisir, we were using CDN to deliver static file so didn't case for us.